# Ruby on Rails, devise: How can i add username and username details ? Need a relational database schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-design, devise

\d users

```
                                           Table "public.users"
         Column         |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      
------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                     | integer                     | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 email                  | character varying(255)      | not null default ''::character varying
 encrypted_password     | character varying(128)      | not null default ''::character varying
 reset_password_token   | character varying(255)      | 
 reset_password_sent_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 remember_created_at    | timestamp without time zone | 
 sign_in_count          | integer                     | default 0
 current_sign_in_at     | timestamp without time zone | 
 last_sign_in_at        | timestamp without time zone | 
 current_sign_in_ip     | character varying(255)      | 
 last_sign_in_ip        | character varying(255)      | 
 created_at             | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at             | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_users_on_email" UNIQUE, btree (email)
    "index_users_on_reset_password_token" UNIQUE, btree (reset_password_token)
```

\d posts

```
                                   Table "public.posts"
   Column    |          Type          |                     Modifiers                      
-------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass)
 title       | character varying(100) | not null
 content     | character varying(500) | not null
 created_at  | date                   | 
 updated_at  | date                   | 
 tags        | character varying(55)  | not null default '50'::character varying
 category_id | integer                | not null default 1
Indexes:
    "posts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I need to keep track who is post a post, so i need username column in posts table.
Shoud i add a username column in posts table or should i add username in users table or should i create a different table for userdetails with username.

I also need to check whether the user is admin or normal user.

Can anyone post complete relational database schema for this purpose ?

devise User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a username in your `posts` table, you just want the user's ID. The username would go in your `users` table.

For your `users` table, you'd want this in the table creation:

```
t.string, :username, :null => false
```

and a `:limit` if you want to limit the length. Then in your `User` class:

```
validates :username, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
has_many :posts
```

If you don't want usernames to be unique then you could drop the `validates :username`; you could also downcase the usernames in a `before_validate` hook and add a unique index on `username` to your `users` table. You might want some flags on the `has_many`, see [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) for details.

Then, when creating `posts`:

```
t.integer, :user_id, :null => false
```

and in `Post`:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Then you can get the username for a post through its `user`:

```
p.user.username
```

If you're trying to add usernames to existing data then you'd need `:null => true` in your migrations for the new columns and you'd have to figure out what you want to do with the missing values in your existing data.

I don't know how any of this would integrate with devise (sorry, I don't use it) or if devise will even care about usernames. Hopefully someone else can fill in the devise parts (if any) and leave me a comment if they do.

Comment: I also need 'role' to check whether it's admin or normal user. I updated original post/question, see that again.

Comment: @guru: You could add a boolean `is_admin` flag to your users, you'd probably want `:default => false` on that flag. Or perhaps use cancan if you need something more complicated for permission handling.

Comment: If i add id_admin in users table, then after logging in how can i check whether the user is admin or not admin ?

Comment: @guru: `if user.is_admin` then you'd have an admin user, `if !user.is_admin` then you'd have a non-admin user.